# how to Order a List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    var f = repository.AllFindDetails_J(id);
    List<string> ports = new List<string>();
    foreach(var p in f.CS.ITFirewalls)
    {
        ports.Add(p.CSPort);
    }
    foreach (var p2 in f.CS.ITRouters)
    {
        ports.Add(p2.CSPort);
    }
    foreach (var p3 in f.CS.ITSwitches)
    {
        ports.Add(p3.CSPort);
    }
    f.AssignedPorts = ports.Sort();
    return View(f);
}
```

but  i got the following error on the `f.AssignedPorts = ports.Sort();`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: The return type of `List<T>.Sort()` is void. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Also, it appears that you're loading values into ports, then sorting AssignedPorts. Did you mean to return the List or the Enumerable?

Comment: as you can see the Ports can be found inside three entities which are ; ITFirewall,ITSwitch, ITRouter. so i need to find all the related ports and pass them to the view as part of the view model.

Comment: @johnG You updated your code slightly, but you're still trying to do the same thing: You can't assign the results of `Sort` -- `Sort` is void and thus returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a void method -- it sorts the existing list but doesn't return anything.

You can either call `Sort` before you pass the list into your view, or you can use the [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method to order the list and return a new `IEnumerable` with the sorted contents.

Option #1:

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    var f = repository.AllFindDetails_J(id);
    List<string> ports = new List<string>();
    foreach(var p in f.CS.ITFirewalls)
    {
        ports.Add(p.CSPort);
    }
    foreach (var p2 in f.CS.ITRouters)
    {
        ports.Add(p2.CSPort);
    }
    foreach (var p3 in f.CS.ITSwitches)
    {
        ports.Add(p3.CSPort);
    }
    ports.Sort();
    f.AssignedPorts = ports;
    return View(f);
}
```

Option #2:

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    var f = repository.AllFindDetails_J(id);
    List<string> ports = new List<string>();
    foreach(var p in f.CS.ITFirewalls)
    {
        ports.Add(p.CSPort);
    }
    foreach (var p2 in f.CS.ITRouters)
    {
        ports.Add(p2.CSPort);
    }
    foreach (var p3 in f.CS.ITSwitches)
    {
        ports.Add(p3.CSPort);
    }
    //OrderBy requires using System.Linq; 
    f.AssignedPorts = ports.OrderBy(port => port).ToList();
    return View(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 return View(f.AssignedPorts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ports.Sort()
f.AssignedPorts = ports;
```

this will give you the result that you had.